# java.sql.SQLException -> NumberFormatException when using .show() method on DataFrame in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive

Whenever I try to use `.show()` method on the `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` object, I get

`java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert column 2 to integerjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{table_name.column_name}" // here table_name.column_table indicates a placeholder I added for the sake of this question`

My SparkSession:

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("My sql connector session")
    .master("local")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

My DataFrame loader:

```
  val currentDF : DataFrameReader = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
                      .format("jdbc")
                      .option("url", hive_url)
                      .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
                      .option("user", username)
                      .option("inferSchema", "true")
                      .option("password", password)
                      .option("dbtable", `{*table_name*}`).load()
```

When I execute following code

```
    currentDF.createOrReplaceTempView("std")
    val newDf = sparkSession.sql("select count(*) as count from std")
    newDf.show()
```

I get

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|  726|
+-----+
```

And when I print the schema using `currentDF.printSchema()`, I have

```
|-- {table_name}.{column_name}: integer (nullable = true)
```

Which indicates that currentDF contains data, but whenever I use `.show()` method I get the above stated error. I search but I was not able to find same error as mine, as I am getting `{table_name.column_name}` and not any dirty data from the table. I am at my wits end and really confused with this. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit**: Tried to change the schema of df by converting all the columns to string type, still getting the same result.

PS : My build.sbt

```
name := "sbt-validation"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.6",
  "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.1.42.Final",
  "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "3.0.0",
  "com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.6.5",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.15",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "3.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0"
    exclude(name="ch.qos.logback", org="ch.qos.logback")
)
```

Comment: I don't know this tech, but from the error messages and your code I think perhaps  might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946449/spark-2-2-thrift-server-error-on-dataframe-numberformatexception-when-query-hive

Comment: @Sajal maybe it goes out of int range?

Comment: I'm almost certain `sparkSession.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")...load()` will not return a **`DataFrameReader`**.

Comment: can you post your full code ??

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("My sql connector session")
    .master("local")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

```
val currentDF : DataFrame = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
                      .format("jdbc")
                      .option("url", hive_url)
                      .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
                      .option("user", username)
                      .option("inferSchema", "true")
                      .option("password", password)
                      .option("dbtable", "(select columna,columnb from schema_name.table_name) alias_name") // Replace your table name & column list as per your requirement.
                      .load()
```

```
currentDF.createOrReplaceTempView("std")
val newDf = sparkSession.sql("select count(*) as count from std")
newDf.show()
```